# Trouble Displaying Optimized Images on Vercel - Need Assistance

Tags: vercel, next.js13

I'm encountering an issue with my web application deployed on Vercel, specifically regarding the display of optimized images and GIFs. I recently optimized these assets using ImageMagick, and they work perfectly on my local development environment. However, when I deploy the application on Vercel, the images do not render as expected. Instead, I see an alt symbol. Even when I reverted to the old unoptimized versions, the problem persists, only affecting the assets that I optimized.

I'd be grateful for any advice or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What version of Imagemagick is on Vercel?  Perhaps it was a version that had a bug?  How do you make calls on Vercel to do the optimization? Please show command or code.

Comment: I deleted optimized versions of images and gifs and changed back to the way it was, works good on localhost but not with Vercel, does  Imagemagick effect any config files or just assets that are optimized?

Comment: You won't get any help if you do not answer the questions in the comments and show some code.